# Creating records on another object

Tags: apex, trigger, soql

I have an Opportunity record. I have a Contract record. I have Provider Profile records. I need Contract Participant records.

My requirement is to have action against the Opportunity record as such that when a Opportunity is put into a "Closed Won" stage, for the Contract in that Opportunity, it looks to find every Provider Profile and create a Contract Participant record for each. In other words, one Opportunity can result in multiple Contract Participant records.

Contract Participant records pull the Contact__c, Practice__c, and Name fields from the Provider Profile records. Contract Participant also pulls Contract2__c from the Opportunity record. I enter in two fields via picklist and date/time.

I am not overly skilled in Apex and I am a trial-by-fire learner, so if the below is a mess, I apologize.

```
trigger createContractPart on Opportunity (after update)
{

    List<Participants__c> cPToInsert = new List<Participants__c> ();
    List<Opportunity> oppList = new List<Opportunity> ();

    for (Opportunity opp : Trigger.new)
    {

        if (opp.StageName == 'Closed Won') 
        {

           Participants__c p = new Participants__c (); 

           p.Contact__c = opp.vAlign_Provider_Profile__r.Contact__c;
           p.Contract__c = opp.Contract2__c;
           p.Contract_Par_s_Practice__c =  opp.vAlign_Provider_Profile__r.Practice__c;
           p.Participant_Start_Date_for_this_Contract__c = date.today();
           p.Provider__c = opp.vAlign_Provider_Profile__r.Name;
           p.Participant_Status__c = 'Active Participant';
           cPToInsert.add(p);

         }

    }

    try 
    {
        insert cPToInsert; 
    } 

    catch (system.Dmlexception e) 
    {
        system.debug (e);
    }
}
```

So, my result from the above is no errors (yay!). I have two issues though:

1. While the trigger does create a record of the correct type, and fills out only *some* of the information. I get everything that isn't being pulled from the Provider Profile relationship. Due to there not being any errors, I'm not sure what the deal is. The relationship seems like it should be sound.
2. No matter how many Contract Participants I should be generating, the system is making two and only two. This confuses me.

Should I try my hand at mapping the results from a Opportunity/Practice Provider SOQL query and trying to generate the entries that way? My knowledge is more SQL based than programming so I get it, but I don't get it.

Comment: Please edit your post to explain the functions of Provider Profile / Contract Participant and how each one is related to the standard objects you mentioned (Opp / Contract / Contact).  Also, what is Practice__c, is that another related object?

Comment: Practice__c is a custom field in the Provider Profile custom object. There is a lookup relationship to the Provider Profile object via Opportunity, which I am leveraging.

Provider Profile and Contract Participant are not directly related, but I'm trying to pull information from the Provider Profile record (which I'm getting from the Opportunity) and inserting it into a Contract Participant record upon creation. 

There are records on the other side of these lookups. It seems like the lookups are hitting null values but they aren't unless there's some strange timing thing at play here.